# Which Reaction is More Thermodynamically Favourable?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, thermodynamics

I have a gaseous mixture containing $\ce{CH4}$, $\ce{CO2}$ and $\ce{H2O}$ that is being reformed via the Steam-Methane Reforming Reaction (SMR), the Dry-Reforming of Methane (DR) or a combination of both. The mixtures are:

Mixture composition
$\ce{CH4}$ = 2.075 mol/s, $\ce{CO2}$ = 2.075 mol/s, $\ce{H2O}$ = 1.0375 mol/s

At 800C, the Gibbs free energy change of the reactions are:
SMR = -45418 J/mol and  DR = -44578 J/mol

Is it possible to predict which reaction will take precedence?  I.e. can I assume that the SMR reaction will consume all of the $\ce{H2O}$ after the remaining methane will be reformed by the dry reforming reaction because the delta G value of the SMR reaction at this temperature is more negative?

Comment: With the minimal relative difference of the reaction Gibbs energies, "both take preference". There would be just minor difference in their equilibrium reaction quotients. SMR will have it slightly higher.

Comment: The reaction rates are most likely to determine the outcome, the fastest reaction could consume all the reactants before the slower one has reacted by much.